# Wordpress sidebar on mobile/small screen

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a problem with the sidebar on a custom made theme I made.

Here is the live site: http://bit.ly/1dqydiI

When I try to view it through a mobile device or by decreasing my browser to 470px or less it starts having a "gap" on the right.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 664px) {

    #main {
        overflow: visible;
    }
    #content,
    #primary,
    #secondary,
    #tertiary {
        background: none;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #primary,
    #secondary {
        width: 100%;
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

The only way to fix this "gap" was by adding `and (min-width: 500px)` above. But that creates another problem. Instead of having a "gap" now I get every content squished in the middle and sidebar trying to fit on the right..

A few pics:
[image: Before the min-width problem "gap"]
New problem..
[image: New problem after min-width..]

I've got no idea why it changes after 470px and causing me the problems above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the padding for your `#content` div.

`#content {
margin: 0 23% 0 0;
}`

The 23% margin-right explains the gap you are talking about.

Comment: margin: 0; doesn't cover that? hmm

Comment: In what browser are you testing? In Google Chrome I can't reproduce any of your screenshots

Comment: Mobile browser: iPhone 4s and BlackBerry OS 7.0 device. Also on IE9 (I know old browser :P)

Comment: On my Internet Explorer 9 it has something to do with the Facebook share button see [this image](http://postimg.org/image/ucaebajir/)

Comment: Damn awesome eye. Give me a few mins to get back and verify this and I'll let you know!

Comment: Helped only a bit mate. The weird thing is that even the sticky bar changes size to fit the rest of the site :/

Comment: The titles of the posts are also too big for the screen. [See this image](http://postimg.org/image/qjx066idz/). You can decrease the font-size to make it fit or wrap the text to the next line if it doesn't fit.

Comment: I also did that mate but didn't change much (I just added word-wrap, you can check it out). This is how it shows on mobile: http://postimg.org/image/ec3jpar9h/ I also wanted to thank you for your time and help mate!

Comment: You're menubar is too big for such small screen, you have to hide some elements or put them on a new line. [Check out this image](http://postimg.org/image/5skz1frrn/)

Comment: The menubar was made for minimum 300px (if I remember correctly) because most mobile browsers are 320xsomething

Comment: That's correct, no problem, glad i could help. Please mark my answer as accepted answer  (if you feel this was the right answer for you).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your scroll+gap error at full width. On which browser do you experience it?

The .entry-date problem in the intermediate level could be solved with:

```
left: -3.4em;
```

at line 1302 of style.css

Also I don't see the space on the right. Maybe can you post the complete URL?

Comment: At full width it is working OK. When you try to view it through a mobile browser is when the problem comes up. I have tried an iPhone 4S and a BlackBerry OS 7.0 both got this problem. Try to resize the browser you are using to around 470px of width and you will see it. Thank you!

Comment: The left: -1.3em; works OK as long as the widht is being kept at 100%. When that changes it goes inside like all the content..